# What does the sentence in italics mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

Student: It's freezing in my room. I think the heat went out or something.

University Employee: Are you sure it's out? *Maybe it just got turned out too far.*

Thanks a lot! ^_^

Comment: I would expect the student to say 'the heat went off' and the employee to say 'it got turned down too far'. Your version doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks! That's from listening material and I guess I misheard. Your explanation makes sense. ^_^ May I ask what " it got turned down too far" means?

Comment: @KateBunting  Maybe this is another US/UK split, but "the heat went *out*" sounds natural enough to this US English speaker - much like "the lights went *out*".

Comment: The employee suggests that someone has turned the temperature control down to a very low level. _Too far_ doesn't make sense if the system is switched right off.